# Basis of a diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

If you construct a diagonal matrix by finding the eigenvalues of matrix A, and putting them on the diagonal, the diagonal matrix $D = P^{-1}.A.P$, but in what basis have you now constructed matrix D?

Comment: $Pe_1,Pe_2,...$

Comment: Isn't this true only when the origanl matrix A was written in the standardbasis $(1,0,0,...),(0,1,0,...)$?

Comment: By $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ I think he means that $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is the basis

Answer (score 1):

The columns of the matrix $P$ are the coordinates of the elements of the "new" basis with respect to the "old" basis.

More specifically, if your "old" basis is $(v_1, \dots, v_n)$ and $P= (p_{ij})$. Then your "new" basis is $w_j= \sum_{i=1}^n p_{ij} v_i$ for $j=1, \dots, n$.

Your concern expressed in comments is in some sense justified, in that you should *not* just take the columns and say this is the "new" basis. (This works if you original basis is the standard basis as you said.)